# Trying to create a bash shell craps game. Output loops a particular portion of it and I can't seem to figure out why

Tags: bash, shell, loops, unix

**Intended Output:**

```
I'm going to pick two numbers, if the sum of those numbers equals 2, 3, or 12...you lose

hmm, I think I'll go with 5 and 4

ya lost, bud

want to try again?
```

**Actual Output:**

```
I'm going to pick two numbers, if the sum of those numbers equals 2, 3, or 12...you lose
hmm, I think I'll go with 5 and 4
So that brings us to a total of: 9
hmm, I think I'll go with 4 and 4
So that brings us to a total of: 8
hmm, I think I'll go with 3 and 1
So that brings us to a total of: 4
hmm, I think I'll go with 1 and 1
So that brings us to a total of: 2
ya lost, bud
want to try again?
```

**Bash Script:**

```
echo "Welcome to the craps machine"
echo  "I'm going to pick two numbers, if the sum of those numbers equals 2, 3, or 12...you lose"

flag=1
temp=1

while [ $flag -le 1 ]
do
number_1=$((RANDOM % 6+1))
number_2=$((RANDOM % 6+1))
echo "hmm, I think I'll go with $number_1 and $number_2" 
let sum=$number_1+$number_2
echo "So that brings us to a total of: $sum"

if [ "$sum" -eq 2 ] || [ "$sum" -eq 3 ] || [ "$sum" -eq 12 ];then
echo ya lost, bud
echo want to try again?
read flag
fi

if [ "$sum" -eq 7 ] || [ "$sum" -eq 11 ];then
echo Youre a winner, champ
echo you want to play again?
read flag
fi

flag=$temp

done
```

Comment: Please use [code format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) so your script (and output samples) are readable. Also, why would you expect it to stop on 9 (=5+4)? And what are `flag` and `temp` supposed to do?

Comment: A [mre] that focuses in on only the specific line of code that doesn't behave the way you want (providing only enough surrounding lines / supporting code to allow the provided sample to be run without changes to demonstrate the difference between actual and desired output) would be more answerable. Right now we need to decode _why_ you think your stated behavior is what the code is expected to do.

Comment: BTW, `let` is an antique, left over from pre-1990s shells that newer shells compliant with the POSIX sh specification aren't required to support. Use `sum=$(( number_1 + number_2 ))` for math, and all shells compliant with modern standards will be required to support that code.